# Database normalization for 1 to many, many to many, many to 1

Tags: sql-server, database-normalization, first-normal-form

For both scenarios I'm using the same Color [lookup] table but storing the data differently. Here's the spec for the records to store:

- Car with Id 1 is available in 3 colors: Blue, Red, White.
- Car with Id 2 is available in 2 colors: Blue, Red

Color

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue |
| 2 | Red |
| 3 | White |

Scenario 1

Car

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

CarColor

| Id | CarId | ColorId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |

Scenario 2

Car

| Id | ColorIds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | 1,2 |

Which is preferred for storing the data?

I've used the structure in both scenarios. Scenario 1 seems to be the most flexible. Needing advice on what is preferred moving forward.

Comment: 1. *Every **single** time*. Why do you think Scenario 2 is normalised? It breaks 1NF.

Comment: ^ agreed. [Bad Habits to Kick : Putting an IDENTITY column on every table](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-putting-an-identity-column-on-every-table).

Comment: What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? Where & how are you 1st stuck following what design method? [ask] [Help][How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

[David Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft)'s comment

> For 1) Remove the ID column in CarColor, and make (CarId,ColorId) the primary key. The ID is useless, and you *need* a unique index on (CarId,ColorId) anyway.

lead me to [this](https://sqlservercarpenter.com/2020/04/28/a-deep-dive-on-clustered-index/) article and has convinced me to use that approach. Specifically, strive for a Natural key when possible, and don't store multiple keys in a column (like scenario 2).